# Using FileChoosers, JNLP API's under Java Web Start to choose files

Tags: java, netbeans-7, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm using the following link to access JNLP API's:

[Using Filechooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

The project: [JWSFileChooserDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#JWSFileChooserDemo)

Basically I want an Open and Save dialog box to get "text" file from user, saving it on server, reading it, processing etc and then showing the same .java file on Website.
For the above 2 lines I've tried:
1. "Integration of Applet with Web Application", this integration works correctly but integration of "Applet .jar file in Web Application" restricts the reading of file.
2. Then I used Servlets to do the same job, but file reading doesn't works therefor me.
3.  Now, I'm using JNLP, Java Web Start for the same.

But according to what I've read on the website, the applet should be signed for these file operations. Under NetbeansIDE there is an option to enable WEB START and self-signing an applet. But this doesn't work for me.
I created the same program as mentioned in the link(using javax.jnlp), but after clicking on Open, it is looping towards else statement which shows "User cancelled save request.".

I think, the above error is due applet is not signed properly as when I run the JNLP file given on the link..it asks for following confirmation i.e.

[image: It asks for confirmation to read/write file access]

So, should I sign an applet using Project properties->WebStart->Enable WebStart->signing->self-signing by generated key or by signing it using keytools which generated certificate i.e .crt file. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other way to do this?

It is possible to use the JNLP API services in an unsigned application.  Having said that, Oracle has decided that in a future JRE, unsigned code will not be loaded at all (using the default security preferences).

Note that those two linked pages refer to two different ways to load files.

1. 'Using Filechooser' uses the `JFileChooser` provided with Swing.  An applet/JWS app. that uses a file chooser needs to declare `all-permissions` in the launch file.
2. The `JWSFileChooserDemo` demo. OTOH, uses the JNLP API file services, and would produce a prompt at run-time similar to the one shown.  *At the moment* these do not need to be signed.

As far as 'self signed' goes, Oracle has also put warnings against using that.  The publisher of a self-signed app. at the moment, will show as UNKNOWN with extra warnings about accepting code from unknown sources.  In the future, the JRE will also automatically reject self-signed code.

For the longer term, the only real option is to supply a digitally signed app.  Signed  using a verified certificate from a Certification Authority.